# How to switch input radio button checked every 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to switch between input radio button checked every 3 second in Next.js, and it is switching from case0 to case1 and case1 to case2 but not case2 to case0. I have intermediate level of knowledge in React and Next.js.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

function Abb() {
  let count = 0;

  const [q1, setq1] = useState(false);
  const [q2, setq2] = useState(false);
  const [q3, setq3] = useState(false);
  const start = Date.now();
  count.toString();
  setInterval(function () {
    let eat = count % 3;
    switch (eat) {
      case 0:
        setq1(true);
        break;
      case 1:
        setq2(true);
        break;
      case 2:
        setq3(true);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    console.log(count + q1 + q2 + q3);
    console.log(q1);
    console.log(q2);
    console.log(q3);
    count++;
    if (count === 3) {
      count = 0;
    }
   
  }, 3000);

  return (
    <>
      <input type="radio" name="addd" id="" checked={q1} readOnly />
      <input type="radio" name="addd" id="" checked={q2} readOnly />
      <input type="radio" name="addd" id="" checked={q3} readOnly />
    </>
  );
}

export default Abb;
```

Comment: Try to set the condition after count++ to `count >= 3`

Comment: Bro is tried same result it stops at last input checked ( on  case2 ) it is not moving to case1 ( first input )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Phil mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67034130/1870780), you should wrap the `setInterval` logic inside a `useEffect` to avoid creating a new `setInterval` every time the component re-renders. I would also suggest you move the `count` variable to state and use that directly to update the `input`s checked attributes, which avoids creating 3 separate states for it.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Abb() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            setCount((c) => ++c % 3);
        }, 3000);
        
        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <input type="radio" name="addd" id="" checked={count === 0} readOnly />
            <input type="radio" name="addd" id="" checked={count === 1} readOnly />
            <input type="radio" name="addd" id="" checked={count === 2} readOnly />
        </>
    );
}

export default Abb;
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time the setter from useState is called (setq1, setq2, setq3) the function Abb is rerun, the component then rerenders. A new interval is intitiated every render because it is at the function level, not inside a useEffect or something.

I would suggest wrapping the code that you only want to have run once inside a useEffect with an empty dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // This code will run once, on mount of the component

    return () => {
        // This code will be run once, on unmount of the component
        // Be sure to clear any intervals, timeouts here
    }
}, []);
```

Also, your input elements have the `checked` property with the state inside. Do not forget that you will need to set the state to be both `true` and `false` in order for you to see the change. Right now none of the setter functions will set the state to false, so never unchecking the button.

Comment: Bro is tried same result it stops at last input checked ( on case2 ) it is not moving to case1 ( first input )

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(function () {
      let eat = count % 3;
      switch (eat) {
        case 0:
          setq1(true);
          break;
        case 1:
          setq2(true);
          break;
        case 2:
          setq3(true);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      count++;
      if (count >= 3) {
        count = 0;
      }
    }, 3000);
  }, []);